How to enable stripe dynamic redirect uri
I am trying to create a stripe integration. In stripe apps - I am able to list static redirect URI but I need the redirect URI to be dynamic.
https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-apps/api-authentication/oauth
Example -
"allowed_redirect_uris": [
    https://app/:id/friends/:fId/show
]

I cannot find any documentation around this if this is supported.

The path requirements for the app manifest fields, such as allowed_redirect_uris are described here.
In short, to support your dynamic path segments (like :id) you're likely going to need to restructure your application/API as manifest URLs must contain a subpath. Using the example you provided, https://app/ is invalid. However https://app/api/ is valid and will cover all subpaths.
